# My app doesn't show up on android studio emulator

Tags: android, xml, android-launcher

It was all good yesterday, but right now it won't show up when I run the AVD.

Don't know if it is my AndroidManifest.xml file which is pretty standard.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.app" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.app.Hoved"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is now fixed all, thank you!
The problem was that I write Android app on Xamarin, so you use flags there instead of declaring the activity in the manifest.

Comment: Gonna need something more than just that to help.  Clean the project, then rebuild, then check if the .apk file exists in `<module>/build/outputs/apk/`.  I'm guessing you have an error in one of your resource xml files which is causing R to fail to generate. I have seen that cause silent errors before

Comment: There is no /apk/ folder in the /outputs/ folder. There is a /logs/manifest-merger-report.txt

Comment: That means your app is failing to build.  The problem is very unlikely to be the manifest file itself, but the resources failing to generate for some reason.  If it was working for you yesterday, hopefully you're working in some sort of version control and can diff what you've changed to see where the problem is coming from

Answer (score 0):

You missing this 2 'lines', it's really important but just past it above (over)    ***< application*** and it's will work.

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

This is the most basic question, you should know that before u start programming in visual studio or eclipse. Just watch some tutorials on youtube it will help you. Good Luck.